# When does the phrase "Some of us..." include the speaker?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage, noun-phrases

I do not recall ever hearing anyone say "Some of us..." without including themselves. It appears to me that oneself is assumed to be part of the subject. However, *some of* is usually used to denote an arbitrary subset of something. Indeed, if I say "Some members of my book club..." no one will presume that I am including myself.

When is the speaker included when saying "Some of us..."? What are some examples where "Some of us..." does not include the speaker?

Comment: "Some of us" quite frequently serves as the subject of a reproach, where the speaker includes him- or herself in the overall group being addressed, but not in the subgroup guilty of whatever the reproach is for. Plenty of examples show up in a Google search for ["some of us have not yet"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22some+of+us+have+not+yet%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#).

Comment: You'll find plenty of examples like the following on the Internet: 'Some of us got away with it; some of us didn't.' [an actual example] The writer can't be in both subsets.

Comment: So, unambiguous sentences aside, is it (generally) safe to assume the speaker is included when there is no information about the context to suggest otherwise? I won't add this to the question since it is probably opinion-based.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Some of us*** is an *[indexical](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/indexicals/)* expression, which means that it picks out different people in different contexts. Sometimes it includes the speaker, sometimes it does not.

Suppose the speaker is a member of a book club that is debating its next book. Suppose the speaker and two others want to read *Moby Dick*, but another three members don't. If the speaker utters:

> "Some of us want to read *Moby Dick*."

then he includes himself when using "some of us."

Now suppose the speaker is a member of a book club that is debating its next book, and that three members want to read *Moby Dick*, but the speaker himself doesn't. Now suppose he is talking to another member who has not yet decided which book they want to read. When the speaker utters:

> "Some of us want to read *Moby Dick*."

he does *not* include himself when using "some of us."

It is probably the case that when speakers use "some of us" they overwhelmingly more often include themselves than not. (But it is virtually impossible to check this conjecture since corpora do not encode the requisite semantic information.)

---

Now for some general diagnostics.

When the speaker does *not* want to include himself, he will often place an **emphasis on the "some."** For example,

> "*Some* of us want to read a terrible book."

Further, examples where the speaker does *not* include himself **easily take parenthetical remarks** which make it clear that he does not include himself. For example,

> "*Some* of us want to read a terrible book (but I don't)."

Comment: I see, thank you. Does this work with "Most of us..." as well? Placing an emphasis on *most* will obviously not have the intended effect, but would you say the rest holds?

Comment: Yes, the same holds for "most of us", but "most of us" probably includes the speaker *even more often* than "some of us" (this is just my native speaker intuition though).

Answer (score 0):

"Some of us..." is commonly used where the speaker wishes to neither exclude nor include himself in the "us". He or she may do so out of modesty when speaking of something that shows them in a good light; conversely, they may use this form if they wish to avoid responsibility but at the same time not alienate their audience.
If the speaker wishes to make their position clear they should use either "Some of us, including oneself..." or "Some of you...", although the latter should be used with caution as it could sound accusative when used in a negative connection.